# Ajax jquery issues, after update from 1.2.6 to 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to web development,

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    dataType: 'html',
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
        $('#loading').hide();
    },
    success : function(html) {
        $('#list_table').html(html);
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

This code works fine with jQuery 1.2.6 but doesn't when I upgrade to 1.7.1.

How can I tackle this problem? 
What are the changes I need to make when upgrading to the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Can you define 'not working'? Why does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: The above code should work in 1.7.1. Can you explain what *isn't* working? Can you recreate your problem in a  website like http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what happens?

Comment: Could you define the term *not working* as a developer, not as a user? Usually users of some application employ those terms. Developers provide technical details such as error messages, ...

Comment: Please include the code wrapping this `$.ajax()` call. Your problem may be with triggering the event, not AJAX.

Comment: This code is part of pagination, for jquery 1.2.6 it just works fine without any error. when I change to latest version above jquery 1.4 then its opening new page with whatever it pull-out through ajax function. I don't get any error. it seems wired. I don't know much about js too. please someone kindly help me out.

Comment: just take out char '@' from code, problem solved. thanks guys